# Compile Tab missing from project properties in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I right click on a project in my solution and go into the properties, I don't see the Compile tab on the left.  I see Application, Build, Build Events and then the next one is Debug.

I've Googled for this but couldn't find anything, and also couldn't find anything here.  Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: what type of project? What language - C#, VB, C++, etc.?  I presume you saw a Compile table in Visual Studio 2010 for the same type of project?

Comment: I was trying to access it in just a regular console application in using c#.

I just tried to create a new project in VB, and noticed that it showed up for that project (I'm new to c#, and have coded in mostly VB).  Does this mean that the Compile tab normally isn't available for c# projects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Compile tab shows up for Visual Basic projects, but not for C# projects.  For Visual Basic it mainly houses constructs specific to VB, like OPTION EXPLICIT, but there are elements like target platform that are found on the Build tab for C#.  The target framework, available under the Advanced Compile Options of the Visual Basic Compile tab is found on the C# Application tab.

UPDATE: With Update 2 of Visual Studio 2012 I'm now seeing Target Framework for a VB project also in the Application tab.

Comment: I was looking for the 'Advanced compiler Options' and it's not on the Application tab

Comment: 'Advanced compiler options' is on the Visual Basic Compile tab.  I notice the original response did even read correctly in the last sentence, so corrected that, and then noticed the Framework is now also appearing on the VB Application tab.