# Web tab missing from Property Pages menu in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have the Web tab missing from the property pages in VS 2012(Don't ask why I'm using the old one) on all projects
I have not installed any extensions or tools (Except NuGet package manager), and it's a fairly new install

I've seen these and none of them help me

[Visual studio project properties tab "web" missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899210/visual-studio-project-properties-tab-web-missing)

[Debug Tab missing from property page in VS2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804052/debug-tab-missing-from-property-page-in-vs2013)

[Compile Tab missing from project properties in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434535/compile-tab-missing-from-project-properties-in-visual-studio-2012)

Answer (score 6):

I had just one web project with missing web tab. Other projects were working fine.
I did the below to fix my problem.

Right click on the project name and click "Unload project", then edit the project and see if you have the below tag with GUIDs in it.
(If not I copied it from another web project.)

`<ProjectTypeGuids>{xxxx};{xxx}</ProjectTypeGuids>`

This tag should decide the type of the proeject.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to create a empty ASP.NET Web Application instead of WCF library to get the Web tab in properties page as well as Enable SSL property provided by IIS express. It's weird MS doesn't make it work automatically for WCF service. Then you create or copy your WCF interface, class and Web.config settings into the new project.